# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''",>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

Eu estou com erro na apresentação do código: apresentando

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''">''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

o código referente o erro é a segunda linha, será que tem como ajudar valeu!

```
 echo   '<div class="letras">
                <label class="alternativa" for="'.$i+1.'" >'.$letras[$i].',
                    <input type="radio" name="1" id="'.$i+1.'" value="'.$numabcde[$i].'">'.$randabcde[$i].'
                </label>
            </div>
        }';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separe as expressões numéricas com `( )`, senão a concatenação acontece antes da operação matemática.

Correção:

```
echo '<div class="letras">
                <label class="alternativa" for="'.($i+1).'" >'.$letras[$i].',
                    <input type="radio" name="1" id="'.($i+1).'" value="'.$numabcde[$i].'">'.$randabcde[$i].'
                </label>
            </div>
        }';
```

Tem outras esquisitices no seu código, como uma vírgula e um `}` sobrando, mas só pelo que foi postado na pergunta, não dá pra fazer idéia da intenção original.

Comment: obrigado pelo apoio !

Comment: Seria legal você separar cada linha com seu echo separado, ou usar o echo somente no lugar das variáveis.

Comment: @FernandoJunior se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor. Obrigado